# How to store uploaded images on the server filesystem to make them available for direct link?

Tags: java, image, tomcat, filesystems

Using Java and Tomcat.

How can I make uploaded images that are stored somewhere on a defined location on the server to be available to a direct link from the browser?

For example: 
On the server: C:\images_folder\example.jpg
Linked from webpage: http://www.example.com/MyWebApp/example.jpg

Is it possible to do or it requires quite a bit of work?

I guess the easy way would be to just store them under the WebContent directory and put them in a directory like uploaded_images under all the jsps files but that seems off.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Tomcat setup includes servlet to serve static content. I believe, you will need to place in webapps/ROOT. Look where documentation goes, that is served when you first start it.

Place your images there and you are done.